# tkinter progressbar not running concurrently with main application

Tags: multithreading, tkinter, progress-bar, python-3.6

I have created a GUI application with tKinter. I am using the threading module so that a progress bar can be used concurrently. The idea is to have the user open a window by clicking on a button. When the window opens, the user can click a button in that window to upload a file. Once the file has been selected, I want a determinate progress bar to appear on the screen and disappear when the processing is done. In my example, I am using time.sleep() to simulate the processing of the file. The problem is that the progress bar does not show up until after time.sleep() is done. It is not packed on the screen until after the process has been completed. I do NOT want the progress bar to be on screen until the file has been selected. All the examples I have seen show the progress bar on the screen from the moment the program starts. That is not the behavior I desire. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to get the progress bar to appear before the main application sleeps and continue running during the sleep time?

Please feel free to ask any questions if anything is unclear.

My code is as follows:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter.filedialog
import tkinter.font as font
import time
import threading

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #  Initialize tk.TK class
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.state('zoomed')
        tk.Tk.title(self, "Stock Management Charts")
        self.new_state = self.state()
        btn = ttk.Button(self, text='New Window', command=self.openWin)
        btn.pack(pady=20)

    def openWin(self):
        PbWin()

class PbWin(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self)
        self.geometry("500x320")
        self.boldVerdana = font.Font(family="Verdana", size=10, weight='bold')
        self.err = []
        self.pbVar = tk.IntVar()
        self.toStop = 0
        self.header = tk.Frame(self)
        self.header.pack(fill='x')
        self.headerLbl = ttk.Label(self.header, text="Progressbar Example", background='#EEEEEE')
        self.headerLbl.pack(pady=10)
        self.importFrame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.dialogBtn = ttk.Button(self.importFrame, text="Start Progress Bar", command=self.openFile)
        self.dialogBtn.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=5)
        self.importFrame.pack()
        self.pbFrame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.pbFrame.pack(fill='x')
        self.pb = ttk.Progressbar(self.pbFrame, max=100, variable=self.pbVar, length=400)
        self.msg = ttk.Label(self.pbFrame, text='')
        self.msg = None

    def clearPB(self):
        try:
            for child in self.pbFrame.winfo_children():
                child.destroy()

        except:
            pass

    def openFile(self):
        self.grab_set()
        fileTypes = (("Comma Delimited Files","*.csv"),("Text Files","*.txt"),("All Files","*.*"))
        filenames = tk.filedialog.askopenfilenames(title="Import Files",filetypes=fileTypes)
        self.numFiles = len(filenames)
        #  If the user has selected a file or files
        if self.numFiles > 0:
            self.startPBThread()
            time.sleep(10)
            print('Done sleeping!')

    def startPB(self):
        startVal = 0
        maxVal = 100
        stepTime = 0.1
        self.pb = ttk.Progressbar(self.pbFrame, max=100, variable=self.pbVar, length=400)
        self.pb.pack(pady=20)
        self.msg = ttk.Label(self.pbFrame, text='')
        self.msg.pack()
        print('Packed!')
        pbVal = self.pbVar.get()
        if pbVal > 0:
            startVal = pbVal

        for i in range(startVal, maxVal):
            if self.toStop == 1:
                break

            self.pbVar.set(i)
            pbVal = self.pbVar.get()
            pbStr = str(pbVal) + '%'
            self.msg.configure(text=pbStr)
            time.sleep(stepTime)

        self.clearPB()

    def startPBThread(self):
        self.toStop = 0
        th1 = threading.Thread(target=self.startPB)
        th1.start()

    def clearErrors(self):
        self.err = []

app = App()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Tkinter is event driven, `time.sleep` should not be used. Try using `after` to create a delay.

Comment: As the `time.sleep(10)`  inside `openFile()` will block tkinter `.mainloop()` from handling pending events and updates, so even `startPB()` is being executed in a thread, the tkinter updates are waiting for processing after `mainloop()` get back the control, i,.e. after exiting `openFile()`.

Comment: @acw1668 Even when `time.sleep()` is not used such as when the file is being processed, the same thing happens. The file is processed before the `startPB()` function is executed. Any suggestions on how to get both the main application to process the file and run the progress bar concurrently?

Comment: @Derek Do you have any suggestions on how I might be able to use `after` in this example?

Comment: Sorry for the delay but we're having an extreme weather event. You might try searching SO for specific solution like this - [tkinter] after with thread and Progressbar